# BeautifulSoup fine_all NoneType object is not callable error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape. However due to this error not able to go ahead.

my cord is...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


indeed_result = requests.get("https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&limit=50")

indeed_soup = BeautifulSoup(indeed_result.text, "html.parser")

pagination = indeed_soup.find("div", {"class": "pagination"})

pages = pagination.fine_all('a')

for page in pages:
    print(page.get_text())
```

and my error message is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 13, in <module>
    pages = pagination.find_all('a')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

for your information,
i had install BeautifulSoup4

Comment: You have a typo. `pagination.fine_all('a')` is meant to be `find_all`with the letter 'd'

Comment: @importJWE I noticed that in the code you included, you have `pages = pagination.fine_all('a')` in which FIND is misspelled. However in your error message it's correct. Could you check if that same line is misspelled in your code? I fixed that issue and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @MendelG wow you guys a genius. however can you tell me what's the different between fine_all and find_all?

Comment: @kantuni wow you guys a genius. however can you tell me what's the different between fine_all and find_all?

Comment: @importJWE `find_all` is a method of BeautifulSoup. So its basically part of the BS code, so you can call it

Comment: @importJWE as stated in the Beautiful Soup documentation "The find_all() method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves all descendants that match your filters." `fine_all()` isn't anything, you just had a typo so it couldn't figure out what to do. Reference: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Answer (score 0):

`pages = pagination.fine_all('a')` has a typo in the word FIND. That should fix it.